# Maven Git project in Eclipse as Java project with content assist

Tags: eclipse, maven-3, m2eclipse, egit, eclipse-kepler

I am having a **Maven project** in Git which I have checked out using **EGit** in **Eclipse Kepler**. Now this project is in my local system but not yet visible in Eclipse as a project. I want to achieve below things:

1) Import it in Eclipse as a Maven / Java project (I am not sure which one is appropriate but I want for example, to be able to reach to a method defined in second java file from my current java file and get the content assist facility of available methods / class)

2) I have run mvn clean install command outside of Eclipse and have got required dependency jar files at C:\Users\xxxx.m2\repository. Now in Eclipse I want to configure my project created in step (1) to be able to use those jar files and do not give compile time error for missing required class.

I tried several options of

Import > Maven > Existing Maven Projects 
Import > Maven > Checkout Maven Projects from SCM 
Import > Git > Projects from Git

but none of them is giving me above two exact functionality.

I am using Maven 3.1.1 and Eclipse Kepler.

Appreciate if someone can guide step by step approach.

Comment: Did you clone it via the Git perspective ?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have already cloned the project using EGit.

After cloning, go to the Eclipse Git perspective:

1. click on the git+ icon/button Then select the 'Working directory'
2. Import as general project

This should import the project in Eclipse and work with EGit.
You should see the current branch next to the project name in the Eclipse Package explorer view.

Comment: Yes I had already imported it as mentioned in the question (Import > Maven > Existing Maven Projects ). But what I am looking for is the way to avail both 1) and 2) from my question.

Comment: @Ronnie, the problem is that you imported an existing project from the local drive, I think you should do it via the Git perspective instead like indicated in my answer. It will be bound with Git. If your project has some Eclipse config files which indicate the Maven nature of the project it should work with Maven in Eclipse, if there is a well configured pom.xml it should work in the console too.